# What is the card_type for MasterCard when using Spreedly with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, spreedly

Spreedly's [docs](http://spreedly.com/manual/integration-reference/payments-api/pay-invoice) do not mention anything.  *Edit: They do indeed.  I plead illiteracy.*

Paypal's [docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment) say the card type is "MasterCard", but actually trying to authorize with that will get you a "Card type is invalid." response from Paypal.

What is the magic string you need to successfully charge a MasterCard?  Examples I have tried which did not work are:

- MASTERCARD
- MC
- mastercard
- MasterCard
- mc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case others come here looking for the other card type strings, here they all are:

- MasterCard: master
- Visa: visa
- American Express: american_express
- Discover: discover

Answer (score 8):

After some trial and error, I found out that the correct answer is "**Master**".

This cost me some money, so I thought I would do some constructive venting by leaving some help for the next developer who wondered.

Answer (score 0):

List of supported cards and their identifiers https://docs.spreedly.com/reference/supported-cards/.  List of credit card numbers to use https://docs.spreedly.com/reference/test-data/.